# Python/BeautifulSoup Web-scraping Issue--Irregular Returns

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've scoured the questions/answers and have attempted to implement changes to the following, but to no avail.

I'm trying to scrape pages of course listings from Coursera's "Data Analysis" results, `https://www.coursera.org/browse/data-science/data-analysis?languages=en&page=1`.

There are 9 pages, each with 25 courses, and each course is under its own `<h2>` tag. I've found some success with the following code, but it has not been consistent:

```
courses_data_sci = []
for i in range(10):
    page = "https://www.coursera.org/browse/data-science/data-analysis? languages=en&page=" + str(i)
    html = urlopen(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")

for meta in soup.find_all('div', {'id' : 'rendered-content'}):
    for x in range(26):
        try:
            course = meta.find_all('h2')[x].text.strip()
            courses_data_sci.append(course)
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

This code seems to return the first 2-3 pages of results and the last page of results; sometimes, if I run it again after clearning `courses_data_sci`, it will return the 4th page of results a few times. (I'm working in Jupyter, and I've restarted the kernel to account for any issues there.)

I'm not sure why the code isn't working correctly, let alone why it is returning inconsistent results.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the ideas...I am trying to utilize both to make the code work.

Just out of curiosity, I pared down the code to see what it was picking up, with both comments in mind.

```
courses_data_sci = []
session = requests.Session()

for i in range(10):
    page = "https://www.coursera.org/browse/data-science/data-analysis? languages=en&page=" + str(i)
    html = urlopen(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")

    for meta in soup.find_all('div', {'id' : 'rendered-content'}):
        course = meta.find_all('h2')
        courses_data_sci.append(course)


    # This is to check length of courses_data_sci across pages
    print('Page: %s  -- total length %s' % (i, len(courses_data_sci)))
```

This actually results in a list of lists, which *does* contain all the courses throughout the 9 pages (and, of course, the `href` info since it isn't being stripped yet). Each loop creates one list per page: a list of all the courses on the respective page. So it appears that I should be able to strip the `href` while the lists are being pushed to the list, `courses_data_sci`.

There are 2 `<h2>` tags per course, so I'm also thinking there could be an issue with the second `range()` call: `for x in range(26)`. I've tried multiple different ranges, none of which work or which return an error, "index out of range".

Comment: Save the HTML for each page and look at it. You may not be getting the page you think you are and/or the page may have a different markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same behaviour using your code.

I changed it in order to use requests:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

courses_data_sci = []
session = requests.Session()

for i in range(10):
    page = "https://www.coursera.org/browse/data-science/data-analysis?languages=en&page=" + str(i)
    html = session.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

    for meta in soup.find_all('div', {'id' : 'rendered-content'}):
        for x in range(26):
            try:
                course = meta.find_all('h2')[x].text.strip()
                courses_data_sci.append(course)
            except IndexError:
                pass

    # This is to check length of courses_data_sci across pages
    print('Page: %s  -- total length %s' % (i, len(courses_data_sci)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. `.Session` didn't work, unfortunately. If you're interested in plumbing it any further, I've altered my original post. I just wanted to see what would happen if I cut back the `try / except`, folding in the idea from @antfuentes87

Comment: This code worked for me and I'm able to get the complete list. Bur you have to use the code as I wrote it; i.e. not just add the line of Session but also use session to get the page:  html = session.get(page) and then use html.text to get the content as in soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text....)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, @GDN. When I was attempting it, I was doubly importing libraries, which seemed to be preventing the code from working. I really appreciate your follow-up comment so that I didn't keep spinning my wheels! So many thanks.